# Merging NumPy arrays and finding columns in Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, data-analysis

I am new to Python. I have two data files in CSV format. I loaded the CSV files data into two NumPy arrays:

```
matrix1 = numpy.genfromtxt(fileName1)
matrix2 = numpy.genfromtxt(fileName2)
```

The rows and cols of both the matrices are unequal.

```
>>print(matrix1.shape)
(971, 4413)
>>print(matrix2.shape)
>>(5504, 4431)
```

I want to combine matrix1 and matrix2 in such a way:

```
mergedMatrix = [ matrix1, matrix2 ]
```

where I can access `matrix1` from `mergedMatrix` using index `0` and `matrix2` using index `1`.

I tried to use `numpy.concatenate` but it does not works on these two matrices. So I tried using pandas merge function after converting `matrix1` and `matrix2` into pandas DataFrames. However, it took a lot of time to do so and all the matrices were merged into a single linear array like `[1, 2, 3,4,5...]` and I didn't had any way to distinguish between `matrix1` and `matrix2` in `mergedMatrix`.

So I am using:

```
#mergedMatrix as a list
mergedMatrix = [matrix1, matrix2]
```

My data contains values like `Inf`. If a column contains value `Inf` in `matrix1` the I want to delete that column as well as the corresponding column i.e. the column with the same column number in `matrix2`.

#### Questions

1. Is there a better way than to use a list `mergedMatrix`?
2. How can find if a `matrix1` column contains such values quickly without checking each element one by one and its column number?

#### Example:

```
matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3],
           [3, inf,0],
           [2 , inf, inf]]
matrix2 = [[0, 4, 2, 7],
           [0, 1, 0.5, 3],
           [1, 2, 3, 9]]

mergedMatrix = [[1, 2, 3],
           [3, inf,0],
           [2 , inf, inf],
           [0, 4, 2, 7],
           [0, 1, 0.5, 3],
           [1, 2, 3, 9]]
```

The result should be:

```
mergedMatrix = [[1],
                [3],
                [2],
                [0,7],
                [0,3],
                [1,9]]

removedMatrixCols = [[2, 3],
               [inf,0],
               [inf, inf],
               [4, 2],
               [1, 0.5],
               [2, 3]]
```

Then I want to split the matrices:

```
newMatrix1 = [[1],
              [3],
              [2]]
newMatrix2 = [[0,7],
              [0,3],
              [1,9]]

removedCols1 = [[2, 3],
                [inf,0],
                [inf, inf]]

removedCols2 = [[4, 2],
                [1, 0.5],
                [2, 3]]
```

so that I can store them into CSV files separately.

Comment: Add a minimal working example with some dummy data including the steps you tried (e.g. using `np.random.rand()` ). You could store your arrays in a list and access them by `list[0]` and `list[0]`

Comment: If you can make the two matrices equal size, you can use `numpy.dstack([matrix1, matrix2])` and have a neat 3D matrix.

Comment: With the way numpy stores its arrays, you'll have to make the dimensions of the two matrices equal.

Comment: Are the second dimensions of your matrices indeed 4413 and 4431?

Comment: @Moritz Added that. Yes I know that I can access the matrices using list[0] and list[1].

Comment: @Evert I'm afraid I can't. Yes they are.

Comment: Sorry, you can't what? Make them the same size? There should be solutions for that; one of them by using masked arrays, for example (mask out extra columns and rows in that matrix, so you can keep infs and nans in the original matrix).

Comment: @Evert  I thought that you meant if I could make them of equal size by reducing my data. To that I answered "I'm afraid I can't"

Comment: No, you would need to expand your 2D arrays to the same size, filling the extra columns and rows with some stopgap (zeros, nans, masked data). Expand both to shape `(5504, 4431)` (well, only one in practice) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Answers in short: technically yes, but not really, no and yes.

1: You should use a list if you want a 3-D list, but I would also make it into an array (`mergedMatrix = numpy.array([matrix1, matrix2])`) such that you can still use the element-by-element logic in the new matrix

2: (Note: these are pretty different questions, so, strictly speaking, *should* be asked in 2 different questions than merged in to one, but I'll survive)

For this, you can remove a column using [numpy.delete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html). To remove a column, use `axis=1` arg, e.g:

```
new_mat = numpy.delete(mergedMatrix, cols_to_delete, axis=1)
```

where mergedMatrix and cols_to_delete are both arrays.

Instead of looping through the array with nested `for` loops to find columns containing an `Inf` number, you can use [numpy.isinf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html), which will you can then substitute for `cols_to_delete` from above (*note: cols_to_delete = numpy.isinf(merged_Matrix)[:,1]

Anyhow, hope this helps out! 
Cheers

Comment: This line from the question, "where I can access matrix1 from mergedMatrix using index 0 and matrix2 using index 1", makes me think the OP wants a 3D matrix.

Comment: And you can't hstack/vstack 2 arrays (matrices) that have unequal 2D shapes; at least one shape will have to be equal.

Comment: Re-reading the question, I think you are correct..? As for unequal shapes, I mis-read "4413" and "4431" as the same.. oops. Corrected for updated part 1

Comment: The 4413 and 4431 could be a typo, since the OP asks about flagging columns in matrix 2 depending on values in matrix 1. In that case, it  would be an example why it's always necessary to copy-paste things.

Comment: could well be. If not though, it is well possible that column 4425 of matrix2 will have an `inf` element which cannot be removed from matrix1, so @OP, watch for that if that wasn't a typo

Comment: @Evert It isn't a typo mistake.

Comment: @Matthew If I use (mergedMatrix = numpy.array([matrix1, matrix2]) then how will I separate them at the end of the program as told in the example?

Comment: double check your example, it is different than what you asked for. You asked for being able to access `matrix1` with `mergedMatrix[0]`, yet you can't do that with the given example; `mergedMatrix[0]` will be `[1, 2, 3]`. Also, if you want to combine with different row lengths (3 and 4 shown in example), you run the potentially program crashing bug of having an `inf` value in column 4 which cannot be removed from the rows with just 3 columns. If there are equal row lengths, look up vstack and hstack (from numpy)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of four solutions:

- Use a list as you already did in your question. There is nothing wrong with that. And you can index your array by `list[0][xx:yy]`
- store your data in a dictionary like {1:matrix1,2:matrix2}
- If you really want to use pandas you would have to add an identifier column to the data before merging it (data1, data2) later on you can either group your data using `groupy` or set an index `df.set_index('id_column')`. But in my opinion that is just too much.
- If you use `np.vstack` or `np.hstack` (depending on the axis on which they are equal, you will loose the information which matrix was which. Unless you generate a mask with a boolean id e.g

  `mask = np.ones(len(merged_matrix))
   mask[0:len(matrix1)] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually need `mergedMatrix`, here's how you can get to `newMatrix1`, `newMatrix2`, `removedCols1` and `removedCols2` without explicitly constructing `mergedMatrix`.

## Locate interesting values

First, let's go find the `inf` entries:

```
import numpy as np
matrix1 = np.genfromtxt(fileName1)
matrix2 = np.genfromtxt(fileName2)

matrix1_infs = matrix1 == float('inf')

# or if you want to treat -inf the same as inf:
matrix1_infs = np.isinf(matrix1)
```

This gives you a boolean 2D NumPy array. For your small example arrays, it will be

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

## Boil it down to columns

You're not interested in individual elements, but which columns have any `inf` values. A straight forward way to find out is to use

```
matrix1_inf_columns = matrix1_infs.any(axis=0)
```

A bit more obscure would be using a combination of linear algebra and boolean algebra to come up with the following vector-matrix product:

```
matrix1_inf_columns = np.dot(np.repeat(True, matrix1.shape[1]), matrix1_infs)
```

The result is the same:

```
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

## Use boolean index arrays for slicing

Something fun happens [when you use boolean NumPy arrays as indices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) for other NumPy arrays:

```
>>> matrix1[:, matrix1_inf_columns] # First index is rows, second columns.
                                    # : means all. Thus here:
                                    # All rows, but only the selected columns.
array([[  2.,   3.],
       [ inf,   0.],
       [ inf,  inf]])
```

Nice. That's just what we wanted for `removedCols1`. But it gets crazier. What happens when you take the negative of a boolean array?

```
>>> -matrix1_inf_columns
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

NumPy negates its elements! This means we can get `newMatrix1` as

```
newMatrix1 = matrix1[:, -matrix1_inf_columns]
# array([[ 0.],
#        [ 0.],
#        [ 1.]])
```

Off course, the boolean index array doesn't know that it was originally constructed from `matrix1`, so we can just as easily use it to index `matrix2`:

```
removedCols2 = matrix2[:, matrix1_inf_columns]
# array([[ 4. ,  2. ],
#        [ 1. ,  0.5],
#        [ 2. ,  3. ]])
```

But where the boolean index array is shorter than the dimension of the indexed array, it will assume `False` for the missing boolean indices:

```
>>> matrix2[:, -matrix1_inf_columns]
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 1.]])
```

That's not the complete `newMatrix2` we want.

## Size trouble

So we have to use a larger index array.

```
>>> matrix1_inf_columns.resize(matrix2.shape[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot resize an array references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function
```

Ow. The [`resize` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html#numpy.resize)? The documentation says that when the requested size is larger than the array, it will (other than the `resize` NumPy array method I tried to use here) not fill in zeros (`False` in case of a boolean array) but instead repeat the array.

So let's see whether we can get a deep copy instead of a view on `matrix1`:

```
>>> tmp = matrix1_inf_columns.copy()
>>> tmp.resize(matrix2.shape[1])
>>> tmp
array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> -tmp
array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

OK, that worked. Let's plug it in as the index for `matrix2`.

```
removedCols2 = matrix2[:, tmp]
# array([[ 4. ,  2. ],
#        [ 1. ,  0.5],
#        [ 2. ,  3. ]])
```

Great, so this still works.

```
newMatrix2 = matrix2[:, -tmp]
# array([[ 0.,  7.],
#        [ 0.,  3.],
#        [ 1.,  9.]])
```

Yay!

## To infinity..[.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Buzz_Lightyear&oldid=669090917#cite_ref-InfinityPhil_18-0) and beyond

It will get a bit more complicated if you also want to take infinite values in `matrix2` into account for the filtering, or if your actual condition is even more complex. But you've now seen most of the concepts you'd need for that.